# Photocell current vs light intensity calibration

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

In Lab experiment, to verity the inverse square radiation law, we observe the solar cell current changes with the distance from the light source. How would we relate the solar cell current and the light intensity impinging upon it?

Comment: Hello, your title is not informative of the question. Please consider rephrasing the title to better reflect the question you are asking.

Comment: Hi Amir, are you asking how to calibrate the photocell i.e. how to relate the current you get from the photocell to the intensity of the light falling on it?

Answer (score 0):

The energy is equal to the intensity divided by the radius squared.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/isql.html

So the further away from the source the less photons per square inch.

Answer (score 0):

"Solar cell" and "photocell" are as far as I know pretty generic terms.

If your device uses the photoelectric effect on a metal cathode, then the current should be proportional to the intensity.

If your device is a silicon photodiode, then using it as a light meter becomes more complicated. Its behavior depends on whether its load has zero resistance, infinite resistance, or something in between. However, the short-circuit current should be directly proportional to the intensity.

If you want to test whether this linearity is actually true, you can do things like exposing the device to multiple light sources and seeing if the current can be predicted based on some background light level plus values attributable to the individual sources. If you have access to accurately calibrated neutral-density filters, that could also work, although there would be the concern that they might not be accurately calibrated outside the visible spectrum. Yet another possibility is to use a speckle pattern from a computer screen. (A grayscale won't work well, because there is a nonlinear gamma correction.)

From your description of the purpose of the experiment, you actually only need to verify that your device is linear. You don't need to know an absolute calibration (which is much more difficult).